# Error establishing a database connection & 502 wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been running a word press website for 2 years on bluehost VPS & and everything has always been fine....

But for last 2 months site is always down for 1-2 hour(in total) each day..

But today it is continously down for 1.5 hour

Errors keep on changing like

- Error establishing a database connection
- 502 Bad Gateway

The Bluehost customer support is saying that its the issue of our websites, something is consuming to much resources

Comment: This should probably be on: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Error Establishing a Database Connection is one of those curses that could be caused by many reasons

**Note: Before you make any database changes, make sure you have sufficient backups.**

**Why it happen?**

- your database login credentials are wrong or have been changed.
- your database server is unresponsive.
- It could be that your database has been corrupted.
- In my experience, many of the times error occur because of some sort of server error however there could be other factors as well.

**Solution**

- Repair a database.Before doing this please make sure you have copy wp-config.php.Currently you are logout from the machine.

**Note** If you are live then take a bakup try this on test environment.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using visual composer and lot of plugins.

Try to optimize your database.You can optimize using wp-optimize or can search wp database optimizing query.Do not forget to backup databases before starting optimization.

Increase wp memory limit using: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

And also update all plugins.Remove unusual plugins.Check if any custom code you added in theme is not conflicting.  That's it.

:)